# Dynamic version selection with macros

Tags: c++, macros, version, versioning

I'm using a 3rd party library in my code and I'm trying to test the newest version of it. The rest of my colleagues have the older version and I'm supposed to submit code that would work on both versions.
Now the problem is that there are functions that I'm using that have different number of parameters in the 2 versions.

```
//eg- in ver_old
DoSomething(para 1, para 2);
//ver_new
DoSomething(para 1, para 2, para 3 , para 4);
```

If I change the code according to ver_new, those who have the old code wouldn't be able to compile and if I use ver_old, I'm not able to compile the code. And there is a function in the library that would return the version as a *char.

Is there a way I can use `#if #else #endif` to select which method to compile? Or to use the version char with a `#define`?

Thanks.

Edit - I won't be able to edit the code in the library.

Comment: you can have default values for the newly added parameters such that old and new should work. Imho using macros to make the code work with both versions is cheating (and btw "dynamic" and "macro" usually dont go so well together)

Comment: I suppose that the library provide a MACRO to tell version number so you can use `#if` on that. else you have to create equivalent on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the caller to `#define` a macro such as `#define NEW_LIB` and then `#ifdef` on that in the new code. If it is defined, use new version, otherwise use old version.

Otherwise, just for reference, the C compatible alternative to function overloading:

```
typedef struct
{
  int    a;
  char   b;
  double c;
  char*  d;
} new_param_list;

void DoSomethingNew (new_param_list* list);

#define DoSomething(...) DoSomethingNew(&(new_param_list){ __VA_ARGS__ })
```

In case 2 parameters are passed, the other 2 will get set to zero.

For a C++ compiler that does not support compound literals, the macro can just as well call a constructor `new_param_list(int a, char b, double c, char* d)` to get an anonymous temporary object.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement two versions in the newer lib, so you have one with only two parameters. It can call the newer version providing some default values for missing arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isnt as clear as it could be, but this is the important hint towards an answer:

> And there is a function in the library that would return the version as a *char.

Macros are expanded even before your code gets compiled. There is no way you can have conditional compilation based on the return value of a function (you can only call it at runtime).

If your code should be working for the old and the new version you need to look for a different solution. For the additional parameters you could provide defaults:

```
foo(int x, double y);              // old

foo(int x, double y, float z = 0); // new
```